# Always check which service is called in components - Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a dashboard with multiple buttons. For this purpose I will have save, delete, edit, clear. Inside I will have multiple components. Example:

- Dashboard

  - Child1
       -grandchild1
  - Child2
       -grandchild1 
       -grandchild2

My strategy was to create a service for each function, following SRP.

```
 create.service.ts
    delete.service.ts
    clear.service.ts
    edit.service.ts
```

My problem is I will have always to make condition on grandchild components.

Example:

```
component GrandChild1

ngOnInit(){

if(isClearService()){
 //do something
}
else if(isCreateService()){
 //do something
}
else if(isDeleteService()){
 //do something
}

}
```

There is a better way for organize this code?

Comment: I assume you GrandChild component will deal more with presentation as compared to business logic. In such case they should be agnostic of their environment/parent and should communicate via `@Input/@Output` properties. Please have a look at the `presentation vs container components` which is a good design practice in almost all frameworks.

Comment: I´m creating reactive forms on grandchild component, so I will have to modify thats forms according to some actions. I don t like @Input/@Output scenario because my container will start to have too much responsabilities

Comment: Then you will end up having grandchild components handling both the presentation (form UI, validation, etc) and business (acting on form data) logic in it. IMO this pollutes the components with tight coupling to logic, making them difficult to maintain and reuse. Nothing wrong with the container having more business responsibility as they don't deal with presentation and not really designed for reuse. Further if needed you can break the business logic into pure function based services and keep the container implementation light. This keeps the design inline with SRP as well for all actors.

Comment: If you have a container with hundreds and hundreds of lines how is that easy to mantain? Container should be a way to control data flowing from service to presentation components. But in my case each component will have different forms. For special att on component I will do business on container? I dont think that is the right direction

Comment: Like I said in earlier comment. `If needed you can break the business logic into pure function based services and keep the container implementation light. ` This should not result in a container with hundreds and hundreds of lines. But you can decide best as I do not know your exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it, but I can think something like this will be a nice solution to your problem.  A rxjs Subject for Object of type T which defines an action.  then additional objects (coming from all different services)  inherit and implement the action of the base object.  so whenever an object comes in from these service.  you can perform the same action but the result will be different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have method in your component which call method in your service. I think you can create one service for all buttons. Here example:

**Service**:

```
export class ChService {
  delete(id: number) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Component

```
import { ExampleService } from './services/ex.service';
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(public ex: ExampleService) {}
  delete(id: number) {
    // do something
    this.ex.delete(id);
  }
}
```